# What are the reasons for "Failed to retrieve logs for this execution"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

In the "G Suite Developer Hub", there is an option on the left column named "My Executions", where you can find out whether the code you developed executed successfully or not.

However, in some scenarios when you want to check out the failed reason, the log message can show as below:
[image]

Though it says "Please try again later" -- actually nothing changes after days.

In my experience, reaching the maximum computer time on the server can be one of  the reason. Just wondering if there is any other reason can cause this error message?